# Directory getting recreated even after complete deletion

Tags: unix

I am stuck with a directory which is not getting deleted. 
Every time I do rm -rf it is not shown in ls for sometime but reappears after sometime.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 11 05:20
```

Above is it's ls -l result.

The directory got created on 11 Aug. But when I delete it, it reappears back with same creation date.

Comment: check `stat directory` which gives you basic information like who has access, owner, and other timestamps, may be due to `cron` or some start up job/service